# How can I add a JDesktopPane to an EditorTopComponent, from an ExplorerTopComponent?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, frame, netbeans-platform

I've been trying to call a method which displays frames in an EditorWindow, when pushing a button in the ExplorerWindow.

There are 3 modules: 

AppEditorAPI which contains this interface

```
package org.app.AppEditorAPI;


public interface Displayer {
    public void Display();
}
```

AppEditor which contains EditorTopComponent

```
@ServiceProvider(service=Displayer.class)
public final class EditorTopComponent extends TopComponent implements Displayer{

    private JDesktopPane jdpDesktop=null;
    private int openFrameCount = 0; 

    ...

    protected void createFrame() {
        MyInternalFrame frame = new MyInternalFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        jdpDesktop.add(frame);
        try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {
        }
    }

    class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

        int xPosition = 30, yPosition = 30;

        public MyInternalFrame() {
            super("IFrame #" + (++openFrameCount), true, // resizable
                    true, // closable
                    true, // maximizable
                    true);// iconifiable
            setSize(300, 300);
            setLocation(xPosition / openFrameCount, yPosition / openFrameCount);
            // Add some content:
            add(new JLabel("hello IFrame #" + (openFrameCount)));
        }

    }
    public void Display(){
        jdpDesktop = new JDesktopPane();
        createFrame(); // Create first window
        createFrame(); // Create second window
        createFrame(); // Create third window
        //Add the JDesktop to the TopComponent
        add(jdpDesktop);
    }
}
```

And AppExplorer which contains ExplorerTopComponent

```
public final class ExplorerTopComponent extends TopComponent {

    ...

    private void initComponents() {

        B_Display = new javax.swing.JButton();

        ..
    }

    private void B_DisplayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        Displayer D = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(Displayer.class);
        D.Display();
    }

    ...

}
```

Below, are links to the project zip file.

http://dl.free.fr/k2Z6DRLrW 
http://www.fileswap.com/dl/lCeFPcUfbg/

After doing some tests. I found that I can't change (add, remove or edit) the variables or properties of the EditorTopComponent.
Like in this case, these two lines;

public void Display(){

```
jdpDesktop = new JDesktopPane();
```

...

```
add(jdpDesktop);
```

}

Are not executed as they should, that's why after the execution, the EditorTopComponent.jdpDesktop still was equal to null and wasn't added to the EditorTopComponent.

Knowing what I want to do, can someone please guide me on the right track ?

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Comment: I'm doubt that SO working this way, but here is Code review, ask for moving (flag your question), much luck

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses.

Comment: @mKorbel and dic19, Thank you for the wishes and I'll try to read more about SO in the future.

Comment: @Robert, the code is a bit long, should I post It in the commentary section ?

Comment: No, edit your question to include it.

Comment: @Robert took me sometime but I've added the snippet as you asked.

Comment: That's more like it. Have an up-vote. Now what exactly goes wrong? Is there an error message?

Comment: @Robert, Not at all, when the button in ExplorerTopComponent is pushed, the Display() function in EditoTopComponent is called, but the Frames are not displayed in the Editor Window

Comment: and are you certain `createFrame();`  is being reached? (step into it whilst debugging to check)

Comment: @Robert, when I call the function Display() from the EditorTopComponent, It works fine, the frames are displayed as they should.
But when called from the ExplorerTopComponent nothing happens.
I've also cleared the Display() function and replaced Its content with a bunch of System.out.println(""), and saw that the call is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, 'made It work... see that's what happens when you avoid reading the books :P

I'm posting the solution if anyone's facing the same issue.

As I mentioned when editing my question, knowing that modifications are not allowed through the lookup, you can either use the InstanceContent variable which can be modified in the lookup, or, use the WindowManager to fitch the EditorTopComponent and call the Display() method.

Good luck